# Update colum based on a select in the same table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table sorted by a column named position:

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| identifier | name  | position |
+------------+-------+----------+
|          1 | test1 |       23 |
|          2 | test4 |      144 |
|          3 | test2 |       68 |
|          4 | test3 |       96 |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

I'm trying to write a query that spaces out the various rows using the position column by a fixed numerical offset based on the already existing order (made by position).

Let's say I wanna space the position by an offset of 50 the table should be updated like this

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| identifier | name  | position |
+------------+-------+----------+
|          1 | test1 |       50 |
|          2 | test4 |      200 |
|          3 | test2 |      100 |
|          4 | test3 |      150 |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

This task is easily solved with a simple for loop from code

```
rows = SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY position
for (i = 0; i < count(rows); i++) {
    UPDATE table SET position = ((i + 1) * 50) WHERE identifier = rows[i].identifier
}
```

But since the table could contain many rows I would like to write a single SQL query directly. I'm using MariaDB 10.

EDIT For clarity

Running `UPDATE table SET position = position * 50` will update the rows by their natural order of insertion. I simply need to keep the order made by `ORDER BY position` but offsetting the position column by a prefixed value.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET position = position * 50`? Or am I missing something in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
UPDATE table AS oo, (SELECT identifier, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position ASC) * 50) AS newposition FROM table) AS np
SET oo.position = np.newposition
WHERE oo.identifier = np.identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with row_number over parttion, to get your new position

```
CREATE TABLE bal
    ("identifier" int, "name" varchar(5), "position" int)
;
    
INSERT INTO bal
    ("identifier", "name", "position")
VALUES
    (1, 'test1', 23),
    (2, 'test4', 144),
    (3, 'test2', 68),
    (4, 'test3', 96)
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 4
> ```

```
UPDATE bal
SET position = rn * 50
FROM (SELECT position as pos, row_number() OVER(ORDER By position) rn FROM bal) sub
WHERE bal.position = sub.pos;
```

> ```
> UPDATE 4
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM bal
```

| identifier | name | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 50 |
| 3 | test2 | 100 |
| 4 | test3 | 150 |
| 2 | test4 | 200 |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HP10w8yC)

Comment: This code will not work because it will update the position by the natural insertion order. I need to update based on the existing order made by position column.

Comment: i edited my answer, to fit your description better